# PyQt5 error during "python3 configure.py": fatal error: 'qgeolocation.h' file not found

Tags: python, macos, pyqt5

**MAC OSX 10.9, Python 3.5, sip-4.17, PyQt-gpl-5.5.1, Qt5.5.1**

Hi,
trying to build PyQt on my system I did the following steps:

1. download/install Qt5.5.1 libraries
2. download/unpack SIP
3. download/unpack PyQt
4. install SIP:

   ```
   python3 configure.py -d /Library/Python/3.5/site-packages --arch x86_64

   make

   sudo make install
   ```
5. tried to install PyQt:

   ```
   python3 configure.py -d /Library/Python/3.5/site-packages
                                  --qmake /.../Qt5.5.1/5.5/clang_64/bin/qmake
   ```

Configuration stopped with:

```
    /Users/werner/OpenSource/PyQt/sip/QtPositioning/qgeolocation.sip:28:10:
                             fatal >error: 'qgeolocation.h' file not found
     #include <qgeolocation.h>
               ^
      1 error generated.
      make[1]: *** [sipQtPositioningcmodule.o] Error 1
      make: *** [sub-QtPositioning-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

I tried to finish installation doing

```
make
sudo make install
```

anyway. But the installation doesn't seem to be complete (e.g. uic, pyuic5 are missing). Here is what my installation directory looks like:

```
>ls /Library/Python/3.5/site-packages/PyQt5
QtBluetooth.so          QtSensors.so
QtCore.so               QtSerialPort.so
QtDBus.so               QtSql.so
QtDesigner.so           QtSvg.so
QtGui.so                QtTest.so
QtHelp.so               QtWebKit.so
QtMacExtras.so          QtWebKitWidgets.so
QtMultimedia.so         QtWidgets.so
QtMultimediaWidgets.so  QtXml.so
QtNetwork.so            QtXmlPatterns.so
QtOpenGL.so             _QOpenGLFunctions_2_0.so
QtPrintSupport.so       _QOpenGLFunctions_2_1.so
QtQml.so                _QOpenGLFunctions_4_1_Core.so
QtQuick.so
```

I couldn't find any useful information when searching for other discussions, so I hope someone can give me a hint on what I'm (maybe stupidly) doing wrong. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Is xcode up to date?

Comment: It is XCode 6.1.1 with the latest Command Line Tools installed just before installation of Qt, SIP, PyQt5.

Comment: I'm having the same problem under Mint 17. I note this question is less than a week old, so I wonder if it's an issue with the installer.

Comment: BTW, it looks like xcode is an Apple thing, and thus irrelevant in my case?

Comment: If you're not working on OSX it is irrelevant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't need this module, the better way to solve that is disabling it on configure.

```
python configure.py --disable=QtPositioning
```

Answer (score 6):

Just yesterday, I also met such a problem. And this is what I do to solve it:

Create a header file qgeolocation.h in /PyQt-gpl-5.5.1/QtPositioning, and copy the content into it from [this website](https://github.com/RSATom/Qt/blob/master/qtlocation/src/positioning/qgeolocation.h). Then I go sudo make and sudo make install successfully.

Though I do not know whether it is right to solve this problem, fortunately, I installed the PyQt and entered eric6. Hope you make successfully, too.

Comment: I tried that approach without success - also copied the location.h into several directories in question such as the /PyQt-gpl-5.5.1/sip/QtPositioning. I also changed PATH and PYTHONPATH in various ways achieving nothing.

However, after some time, I decided to just delete the entire QTPositioning directory (that is to say the one mentioned above and the /PyQt-gpl-5.5.1/QtPositioning)

Comment: After that the whole process went smooth, installation seems to work. Of course it lacks the deleted functionality. For now, I can live with that.

Comment: Thanks so much for this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the location.h header file for me on OSX 10.11.1.
I had the problem in both PyQt-gpl-5.5.1 and PyQt-gpl-5.5.2, but after adding the
file, was able to build.

Answer (score 0):

The way of creating a qgeolocation.h in /PyQt-gpl-5.5.1/QtPositioning worked for me. The QtPositioning.so was created.

Comment: Can you expand your answer a bit? I don't feel that this provides a complete answer. Can you explain this method of creating `qgeolocation.h`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also take the header file from your qt source folder (you have installed the source files together with binaries, right?), it is located here:

```
/Src/qtlocation/src/positioning/qgeolocation.h
```

and then just copy it into:

```
/PyQt-gpl-X.X.X/QtPositioning/qgeolocation.h
```

as follows. It should solve the problem in 99.9% cases.